# Get all records in table without field

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

I have a table in **RethinkDB** where I want to retrieve all records where the field `single` is not set. Because there is no enforced schema some documents stored do not follow the exact same structure.

Example data in table:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "age": 27,
  "sex": "female",
  "single": true
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "sex": "female",
  "age": 40
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "age": 45,
  "sex": "male",
  "single": false
},
{
  "id": "4",
  "sex": "male",
  "age": 16
}
```

I need to write a **ReQL** query that would retrieve records 2 and 4. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you retrieve all the documents without the field `single` or with the field `single` being `null`.

```
r.table('data').filter(function(doc) {
    return doc.hasFields('single').not();
}).run().then(...).error(...)
```

If you just want undefined fields:

```
r.table('data').filter(function(doc) {
     return doc('single').ne(null);
}).run().then(...).error(...)
```

This works because if `single` is not a key, an error will be returned in filter, and the document will be skipped.

Documentation:

- for `hasFields`: http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/has_fields/
- for `filter`: http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/filter/

If you have a lot of data, you may want to use an index too.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
var data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "age": 27,
  "sex": "female",
  "single": true
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "sex": "female",
  "age": 40
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "age": 45,
  "sex": "male",
  "single": false
},
{
  "id": "4",
  "sex": "male",
  "age": 16
}];


var filtered = data.filter(function(elem){return typeof(elem.single) !== 'undefined';}));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a native solution, here is a plain non-index example:

```
var result = [];
original.forEach(value) {
  if(value.single != null) {
    result.push(value);
  }
}
```

For mongodb, you can read about queries and projections here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/